# how to write the sql statement?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables as follows in my database. this is used to a application just like foursqure. i need help with the problem of writing the sql statement i have asked in the bottom of this.

thank you

user_details

```
user_id | fname
----------------
   1    | Losh
   8    | Dush
   9    | Rosh
  10    | NELL
```

friends

```
user_idf |user_idff
----------------
   1     |   8
   8     |   9
   10    |   1
```

Check_in

```
check_in_id |user_id | place    | date
--------------------------------------------
       1    |   8    | Hotel    | 01/01/2012
       2    |   9    | Home     | 05/01/2012
       3    |   1    | Junction | 08/01/2012
       4    |   1    | Rest     | 11/01/2012
       5    |   9    | Hotel    | 15/01/2012
       6    |   8    | Home     | 15/01/2012
```

i get the user's who are friends with 8 and user 8 details AND the check in places as follows

```
SELECT a.`user_id`, a.`fname` , b.*
FROM `user_details` a, `check_in` b
WHERE (b.user_id = 8 
OR b.user_id in (select user_idf from friends where user_idff = '8' union select user_idff from friends where user_idf = '8')) AND b.user_id = a.user_id
```

*how do i write the sql to select who are friends with 8 and user 8 details AND the **last** check in place of those users*

explanation::

i seeks for a answer such as

```
user id    name     place   date
   1       LOSH     Rest  11/01/2012
   8       DUSH     HOME  15/01/2012
   9       ROSH     HOTEL 15/01/2012
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(SELECT a.user_id, a.place, b.fname, a.date, a.time, a.check_in_id
FROM (SELECT * FROM check_in ORDER BY `date` DESC) as a, user_details as b
WHERE a.user_id = b.user_id AND (a.user_id in (select user_idf from friends where user_idff = '8' union select user_idff from friends where user_idf = '8') OR a.user_id = 8)
GROUP BY a.user_id)

above query gave me the required answer.

thank you all for the help given

Answer (score 2):

Join it to the table returned by:

```
(SELECT `user_id`, `place` FROM Check_in GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY `date` DESC)
```

That should give you one entry per user, and since it's sorted in reverse by date, that entry should be the most recent.

> But when i group by it gives me the first dates not the latest date

How about this:

```
(SELECT user_id, place
   FROM (SELECT * FROM Check_in ORDER BY `date` DESC) tmp
   GROUP BY user_id)
```

Comment: But when i group by it gives me the first dates not the latest date

Comment: I edited my answer with something else to try.  I'm sure I've done this same kind of thing this way before =)

Comment: Hy yes it worked... thnx :) now i have to get the friends in to this and get the users and places as i have edited in the question. can u see the last table. thats' what i want to get as the output

Comment: No worries...  To get the friends, just join that whole result (note I put it in parentheses because of that) with your original query, matching user_id.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, fname, c.place
FROM user_details u
     INNER JOIN (SELECT IF(user_idff = 8, user_idf, user_idff) AS user_id
                 FROM friends
                 WHERE (user_idff = 8 OR user_idf = 8)
                ) f
                ON u.user_id = f.user_id
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT c1.user_id, place
                FROM Check_in c1
                     LEFT JOIN  Check_in c2
                         ON c1.user_id = c2.user_id AND
                            c1.date < c2.date
                WHERE c2.date IS NULL
               ) c
               ON u.user_id = c.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't break ties but it's a straighforward way of answering your question.

**EDIT**
I just re-read you question and I see that you want user 8 info also. It's not clear whether you want user 8 as a separate row or with info in line with the friends' rows.

```
select *
from
    friends as f inner join check_in as ci on ci.user_id = f.user_idff
    inner join user_details as ud on ud.user_id = f.user_idff
    inner join user_details as ud8 on ud8.user_id = f.user_idf
where
    f.user_idf = 8
    and date = (
        select max(date)
        from friends as f2 inner join check_in as ci on ci.user_id = f2.user_idff
        where f2.user_idf = f.user_idf
    )
```

**EDIT 2**
You request may be a small bit unclear about determining which check-in location to return. Use this option if you want the latest location of each friend individually. The first query finds the most recent location among *all* friends. Obviously these are two variations on an identical theme.

```
select *
from
    friends as f inner join check_in as ci on ci.user_id = f.user_idff
    inner join user_details as ud on ud.user_id = f.user_idff
    inner join user_details as ud8 on ud8.user_id = f.user_idf
where
    f.user_idf = 8
    and date = (
        select max(date)
        from check_in as ci
        where ci.user_id = f.user_idff
    )
```